# Авторизация без использования пароля FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

Всем привет. Моя цель - реализовать авторизацию без использования пароля. Только по полю username. Возможно ли это сделать без создания кастомного UserProvider именно с использованием FOSUserBundle?